# Django Rest Framework: One URL for POST, one URL for GET on the same APIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am currently writing a `POST` request to create an `A` record:

```
client.post(url, {'name' : 'foo', 'another_field' : 2})
```

And on the server side, on the view, I have:

```
class AQuery(generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = A.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ASerializer

    def get(self, request, param1, param2, format=None):
        ... # do some special query based off of param1 and 2.

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=False) 
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(...)
        return Response(...)
```

As you can see, I want `param1` and `param2` to be captured in the url, and so in the `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # for GET
    path('A/<str:param1>/<path:param2>', views.AQuery.as_view(), name='A query GET')
    # for POST
    path('A', views.AQuery.as_view(), name='A query POST')
    ...
]
```

Obviously, I can add the `param1` and `param2` to the `post` function def, but they would just be *there*, with no purpose. Seems like bad code smell to me.

How would I implement something like this, and explicitly disallow the client to make a POST request to `A/param1/param2`, and explicitly disallow the client to make a GET request to `A/`?

## What I've tried

I tried to turn the View into a `viewsets.ModelViewSet`, and added the following:

```
a_get_query = AQuery.as_view({'get':'get'})
a_post_query = AQuery.as_view({'post':'post'})
```

and in my `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
        # for GET
        path('A/<str:param1>/<path:param2>', views.a_get_query, name='A query GET')
        # for POST
        path('A', views.a_post_query, name='A query POST')
        ...
    ]
```

But I get the following error:

> TypeError: The `actions` argument must be provided when calling `.as_view()` on a ViewSet. For example `.as_view({'get': 'list'})`

and I'm not quite sure where it's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach works as expected for me. I had to make a couple of minor changes however:

1) I had to change the names of the functions from `get` and `post` to `do_get` and `do_post`. Django seems to do something special when the functions are named the same as the HTTP methods themselves.

2) I inlined calling `as_view()` directly in the `urls.py`.

So after doing that:

```
urlpatterns = [
        # for GET
        path('A/<str:param1>/<path:param2>', views.AQuery.as_view({'get':'do_get'}), name='A query GET')
        # for POST
        path('A', views.AQuery.as_view({'post':'do_post'}), name='A query POST')
        ...
    ]
```

The result:

```
GET   A/param1/param2  -> 200 OK
GET   A/               -> 405 Method Not Allowed

POST  A/param1/param2  -> 405 Method Not Allowed
POST  A/               -> 200 OK
```

Comment: I tried inlining it and renaming it and realized that the issue was gone for some reason. Though I'm not sure what the reason is, I have accepted your answer :)